# Tesseract [OCR] - only numbers and euro symbol

Tags: image, ocr, tesseract

At the moment I'm using `tesseract a.tif output nobatch digits` to parse an image that contains only numbers.

I'm in the need of parsing an image that contains numbers and Euro symbol. How can I do that with tesseract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the file **digits** under **tessdata\configs** to include the € symbol.

Comment: I'm in OSx. How come I can't find this file? What's its path? Howver thanks for your reply!

Comment: Found in `usr\local\share\tessdata`! Thanks!